# Problem using callback with multiple arguments via ApproximateTime synchronizer

Tags: ros, callback, approximatetime

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have always no success in using callback with multiple arguments (in my use case here is three arguments) be it using exact time synchronizer or approximate one.

My implementation is like below:

```
void callback(const std_msgs::Float32::ConstPtr& msg1, const std_msgs::Float32::ConstPtr& msg2, const std_msgs::Float32::ConstPtr& msg3)
{
      // some processing
}

message_filters::Subscriber<std_msgs::Float32> sub1(n, "chatter", 1);
message_filters::Subscriber<std_msgs::Float32> sub2(n, "chatter", 1);
message_filters::Subscriber<std_msgs::Float32> sub3(n, "chatter", 1);

typedef sync_policies::ApproximateTime<std_msgs::Float32, std_msgs::Float32, std_msgs::Float32> MySyncPolicy;
// ApproximateTime takes a queue size as its constructor argument, hence MySyncPolicy(10)
Synchronizer<MySyncPolicy> sync(MySyncPolicy(10), sub1, sub2, sub3);
sync.registerCallback(boost::bind(&callback, _1, _2, _3));
```

Updated complete error:

```
{-------------------------------------------------------------------------------           
/opt/ros/fuerte/include/message_filters/synchronizer.h:268:5:   instantiated from ‘void message_filters::Synchronizer<Policy>::connectInput(F0&, F1&, F2&, F3&, F4&, F5&) [with F0 = message_filters::Subscriber<std_msgs::Float32_<std::allocator<void> > >, F1 = message_filters::Subscriber<std_msgs::Float32_<std::allocator<void> > >, F2 = message_filters::Subscriber<std_msgs::Float32_<std::allocator<void> > >, F3 = message_filters::NullFilter<message_filters::NullType>, F4 = message_filters::NullFilter<message_filters::NullType>, F5 = message_filters::NullFilter<message_filters::NullType>, Policy = message_filters::sync_policies::ApproximateTime<std_msgs::Float32_<std::allocator<void> >, std_msgs::Float32_<std::allocator<void> >, std_msgs::Float32_<std::allocator<void> > >]’/opt/ros/fuerte/include/message_filters/synchronizer.h:261:5:   instantiated from ‘void message_filters::Synchronizer<Policy>::connectInput(F0&, F1&, F2&, F3&, F4&) [with F0 = message_filters::Subscriber<std_msgs::Float32_<std::allocator<void> > >, F1 = message_filters::Subscriber<std_msgs::Float32_<std::allocator<void> > >, F2 = message_filters::Subscriber<std_msgs::Float32_<std::allocator<void> > >, F3 = message_filters::NullFilter<message_filters::NullType>, F4 = message_filters::NullFilter<message_filters::NullType>, Policy = message_filters::sync_policies::ApproximateTime<std_msgs::Float32_<std::allocator<void> >, std_msgs::Float32_<std::allocator<void> >, std_msgs::Float32_<std::allocator<void> > >]’/opt/ros/fuerte/include/message_filters/synchronizer.h:254:5:   instantiated from ‘void message_filters::Synchronizer<Policy>::connectInput(F0&, F1&, F2&, F3&) [with F0 = message_filters::Subscriber<std_msgs::Float32_<std::allocator<void> > >, F1 = message_filters::Subscriber<std_msgs::Float32_<std::allocator<void> > >, F2 = message_filters::Subscriber<std_msgs::Float32_<std::allocator<void> > >, F3 = message_filters::NullFilter<message_filters::NullType>, Policy = message_filters::sync_policies::ApproximateTime<std_msgs::Float32_<std::allocator<void> >, std_msgs::Float32_<std::allocator<void> >, std_msgs::Float32_<std::allocator<void> > >]’/opt/ros/fuerte/include/message_filters/synchronizer.h:247:5:   instantiated from ‘void message_filters::Synchronizer<Policy>::connectInput(F0&, F1&, F2&) [with F0 = message_filters::Subscriber<std_msgs::Float32_<std::allocator<void> > >, F1 = message_filters::Subscriber<std_msgs::Float32_<std::allocator<void> > >, F2 = message_filters::Subscriber<std_msgs::Float32_<std::allocator<void> > >, Policy = message_filters::sync_policies::ApproximateTime<std_msgs::Float32_<std::allocator<void> >, std_msgs::Float32_<std::allocator<void> >, std_msgs::Float32_<std::allocator<void> > >]’/opt/ros/fuerte/include/message_filters/synchronizer.h:168:5:   instantiated from ‘message_filters::Synchronizer<Policy>::Synchronizer(const Policy&, F0&, F1&, F2&) [with F0 = message_filters::Subscriber<std_msgs::Float32_<std::allocator<void> > >, F1 = message_filters::Subscriber<std_msgs::Float32_<std::allocator<void> > >, F2 = message_filters::Subscriber<std_msgs::Float32_<std::allocator<void> > >, Policy = message_filters::sync_policies::ApproximateTime<std_msgs::Float32_<std::allocator<void> >, std_msgs::Float32_<std::allocator<void> >, std_msgs::Float32_<std::allocator<void> > >]’/home/abc/ros_workspace/prototype/src/prototype_node.cpp:141:68:   instantiated from here /opt/ros/fuerte/include/message_filters/sync_policies/approximate_time.h:620:119: error: ‘value’ is not a member of ‘ros::message_traits::TimeStamp<std_msgs::Float32_<std::allocator<void> >, void>’/opt/ros/fuerte/include/message_filters/sync_policies/approximate_time.h: In member function ‘ros::Time message_filters::sync_policies::ApproximateTime<M0, M1, M2, M3, M4, M5, M6, M7, M8>::getVirtualTime() [with int i = 1, M0 = std_msgs::Float32_<std::allocator<void> >, M1 = std_msgs::Float32_<std::allocator<void> >, M2 = std_msgs::Float32_<std::allocator<void> >, M3 = message_filters::NullType, M4 = message_filters::NullType, M5 = message_filters::NullType, M6 = message_filters::NullType, M7 = message_filters::NullType, M8 = message_filters::NullType]’:/opt/ros/fuerte/include/message_filters/sync_policies/approximate_time.h:646:5:   instantiated from ‘void message_filters::sync_policies::ApproximateTime<M0, M1, M2, M3, M4, M5, M6, M7, M8>::getVirtualCandidateBoundary(uint32_t&, ros::Time&, bool) [with M0 = std_msgs::Float32_<std::allocator<void> >, M1 = std_msgs::Float32_<std::allocator<void> >, M2 = std_msgs::Float32_<std::allocator<void> >, M3 = message_filters::NullType, M4 = message_filters::NullType, M5 = message_filters::NullType, M6 = message_filters::NullType, M7 = message_filters::NullType, M8 = message_filters::NullType, uint32_t = unsigned int]’/opt/ros/fuerte/include/message_filters/sync_policies/approximate_time.h:634:65:   instantiated from ‘void message_filters::sync_policies::ApproximateTime<M0, M1, M2, M3, M4, M5, M6, M7, M8>::getVirtualCandidateEnd(uint32_t&, ros::Time&) [with M0 = std_msgs::Float32_<std::allocator<void> >, M1 = std_msgs::Float32_<std::allocator<void> >, M2 = std_msgs::Float32_<std::allocator<void> >, M3 = message_filters::NullType, M4 = message_filters::NullType, M5 = message_filters::NullType, M6 = message_filters::NullType, M7 = message_filters::NullType, M8 = message_filters::NullType, uint32_t = unsigned int]’/opt/ros/fuerte/include/message_filters/sync_policies/approximate_time.h:763:11:   instantiated from ‘void message_filters::sync_policies::ApproximateTime<M0, M1, M2, M3, M4, M5, M6, M7, M8>::process() [with M0 = std_msgs::Float32_<std::allocator<void> >, M1 = std_msgs::Float32_<std::allocator<void> >, M2 = std_msgs::Float32_<std::allocator<void> >, M3 = message_filters::NullType, M4 = message_filters::NullType, M5 = message_filters::NullType, M6 = message_filters::NullType, M7 = message_filters::NullType, M8 = message_filters::NullType]’/opt/ros/fuerte/include/message_filters/sync_policies/approximate_time.h:212:9:   instantiated from ‘void message_filters::sync_policies::ApproximateTime<M0, M1, M2, M3, M4, M5, M6, M7, M8>::add(const typename boost::mpl::at_c<typename message_filters::PolicyBase<M0, M1, M2, M3, M4, M5, M6, M7, M8>::Events, i>::type&) [with int i = 0, M0 = std_msgs::Float32_<std::allocator<void> >, M1 = std_msgs::Float32_<std::allocator<void> >, M2 = std_msgs::Float32_<std::allocator<void> >, M3 = message_filters::NullType, M4 = message_filters::NullType, M5 = message_filters::NullType, M6 = message_filters::NullType, M7 = message_filters::NullType, M8 = message_filters::NullType, typename boost::mpl::at_c<typename message_filters::PolicyBase<M0, M1, M2, M3, M4, M5, M6, M7, M8>::Events, i>::type = ros::MessageEvent<const std_msgs::Float32_<std::allocator<void> > >]’/opt/ros/fuerte/include/message_filters/synchronizer.h:358:5:   instantiated from ‘void message_filters::Synchronizer<Policy>::cb(const typename boost::mpl::at_c<typename Policy::Events, i>::type&) [with int i = 0, Policy = message_filters::sync_policies::ApproximateTime<std_msgs::Float32_<std::allocator<void> >, std_msgs::Float32_<std::allocator<void> >, std_msgs::Float32_<std::allocator<void> > >, typename boost::mpl::at_c<typename Policy::Events, i>::type = ros::MessageEvent<const std_msgs::Float32_<std::allocator<void> > >]’/opt/ros/fuerte/include/message_filters/synchronizer.h:290:5:   [ skipping 3 instantiation contexts ]/opt/ros/fuerte/include/message_filters/synchronizer.h:268:5:   instantiated from ‘void message_filters::Synchronizer<Policy>::connectInput(F0&, F1&, F2&, F3&, F4&, F5&) [with F0 = message_filters::Subscriber<std_msgs::Float32_<std::allocator<void> > >, F1 = message_filters::Subscriber<std_msgs::Float32_<std::allocator<void> > >, F2 = message_filters::Subscriber<std_msgs::Float32_<std::allocator<void> > >, F3 = message_filters::NullFilter<message_filters::NullType>, F4 = message_filters::NullFilter<message_filters::NullType>, F5 = message_filters::NullFilter<message_filters::NullType>, Policy = message_filters::sync_policies::ApproximateTime<std_msgs::Float32_<std::allocator<void> >, std_msgs::Float32_<std::allocator<void> >, std_msgs::Float32_<std::allocator<void> > >]’/opt/ros/fuerte/include/message_filters/synchronizer.h:261:5:   instantiated from ‘void message_filters::Synchronizer<Policy>::connectInput(F0&, F1&, F2&, F3&, F4&) [with F0 = message_filters::Subscriber<std_msgs::Float32_<std::allocator<void> > >, F1 = message_filters::Subscriber<std_msgs::Float32_<std::allocator<void> > >, F2 = message_filters::Subscriber<std_msgs::Float32_<std::allocator<void> > >, F3 = message_filters::NullFilter<message_filters::NullType>, F4 = message_filters::NullFilter<message_filters::NullType>, Policy = message_filters::sync_policies::ApproximateTime<std_msgs::Float32_<std::allocator<void> >, std_msgs::Float32_<std::allocator<void> >, std_msgs::Float32_<std::allocator<void> > >]’/opt/ros/fuerte/include/message_filters/synchronizer.h:254:5:   instantiated from ‘void message_filters::Synchronizer<Policy>::connectInput(F0&, F1&, F2&, F3&) [with F0 = message_filters::Subscriber<std_msgs::Float32_<std::allocator<void> > >, F1 = message_filters::Subscriber<std_msgs::Float32_<std::allocator<void> > >, F2 = message_filters::Subscriber<std_msgs::Float32_<std::allocator<void> > >, F3 = message_filters::NullFilter<message_filters::NullType>, Policy = message_filters::sync_policies::ApproximateTime<std_msgs::Float32_<std::allocator<void> >, std_msgs::Float32_<std::allocator<void> >, std_msgs::Float32_<std::allocator<void> > >]’/opt/ros/fuerte/include/message_filters/synchronizer.h:247:5:   instantiated from ‘void message_filters::Synchronizer<Policy>::connectInput(F0&, F1&, F2&) [with F0 = message_filters::Subscriber<std_msgs::Float32_<std::allocator<void> > >, F1 = message_filters::Subscriber<std_msgs::Float32_<std::allocator<void> > >, F2 = message_filters::Subscriber<std_msgs::Float32_<std::allocator<void> > >, Policy = message_filters::sync_policies::ApproximateTime<std_msgs::Float32_<std::allocator<void> >, std_msgs::Float32_<std::allocator<void> >, std_msgs::Float32_<std::allocator<void> > >]’/opt/ros/fuerte/include/message_filters/synchronizer.h:168:5:   instantiated from ‘message_filters::Synchronizer<Policy>::Synchronizer(const Policy&, F0&, F1&, F2&) [with F0 = message_filters::Subscriber<std_msgs::Float32_<std::allocator<void> > >, F1 = message_filters::Subscriber<std_msgs::Float32_<std::allocator<void> > >, F2 = message_filters::Subscriber<std_msgs::Float32_<std::allocator<void> > >, Policy = message_filters::sync_policies::ApproximateTime<std_msgs::Float32_<std::allocator<void> >, std_msgs::Float32_<std::allocator<void> >, std_msgs::Float32_<std::allocator<void> > >]’/home/abc/ros_workspace/prototype/src/prototype_node.cpp:141:68:   instantiated from here/opt/ros/fuerte/include/message_filters/sync_policies/approximate_time.h:612:117: error: ‘value’ is not a member of ‘ros::message_traits::TimeStamp<std_msgs::Float32_<std::allocator<void> >, void>’/opt/ros/fuerte/include/message_filters/sync_policies/approximate_time.h:620:119: error: ‘value’ is not a member of ‘ros::message_traits::TimeStamp<std_msgs::Float32_<std::allocator<void> >, void>’/opt/ros/fuerte/include/message_filters/sync_policies/approximate_time.h: In member function ‘ros::Time message_filters::sync_policies::ApproximateTime<M0, M1, M2, M3, M4, M5, M6, M7, M8>::getVirtualTime() [with int i = 2, M0 = std_msgs::Float32_<std::allocator<void> >, M1 = std_msgs::Float32_<std::allocator<void> >, M2 = std_msgs::Float32_<std::allocator<void> >, M3 = message_filters::NullType, M4 = message_filters::NullType, M5 = message_filters::NullType, M6 = message_filters::NullType, M7 = message_filters::NullType, M8 = message_filters::NullType]’:/opt/ros/fuerte/include/message_filters/sync_policies/approximate_time.h:647:5:   instantiated from ‘void message_filters::sync_policies::ApproximateTime<M0, M1, M2, M3, M4, M5, M6, M7, M8>::getVirtualCandidateBoundary(uint32_t&, ros::Time&, bool) [with M0 = std_msgs::Float32_<std::allocator<void> >, M1 = std_msgs::Float32_<std::allocator<void> >, M2 = std_msgs::Float32_<std::allocator<void> >, M3 = message_filters::NullType, M4 = message_filters::NullType, M5 = message_filters::NullType, M6 = message_filters::NullType, M7 = message_filters::NullType, M8 = message_filters::NullType, uint32_t = unsigned int]’/opt/ros/fuerte/include/message_filters/sync_policies/approximate_time.h:634:65:   instantiated from ‘void message_filters::sync_policies::ApproximateTime<M0, M1, M2, M3, M4, M5, M6, M7, M8>::getVirtualCandidateEnd(uint32_t&, ros::Time&) [with M0 = std_msgs::Float32_<std::allocator<void> >, M1 = std_msgs::Float32_<std::allocator<void> >, M2 = std_msgs::Float32_<std::allocator<void> >, M3 = message_filters::NullType, M4 = message_filters::NullType, M5 = message_filters::NullType, M6 = message_filters::NullType, M7 = message_filters::NullType, M8 = message_filters::NullType, uint32_t = unsigned int]’/opt/ros/fuerte/include/message_filters/sync_policies/approximate_time.h:763:11:   instantiated from ‘void message_filters::sync_policies::ApproximateTime<M0, M1, M2, M3, M4, M5, M6, M7, M8>::process() [with M0 = std_msgs::Float32_<std::allocator<void> >, M1 = std_msgs::Float32_<std::allocator<void> >, M2 = std_msgs::Float32_<std::allocator<void> >, M3 = message_filters::NullType, M4 = message_filters::NullType, M5 = message_filters::NullType, M6 = message_filters::NullType, M7 = message_filters::NullType, M8 = message_filters::NullType]’/opt/ros/fuerte/include/message_filters/sync_policies/approximate_time.h:212:9:   instantiated from ‘void message_filters::sync_policies::ApproximateTime<M0, M1, M2, M3, M4, M5, M6, M7, M8>::add(const typename boost::mpl::at_c<typename message_filters::PolicyBase<M0, M1, M2, M3, M4, M5, M6, M7, M8>::Events, i>::type&) [with int i = 0, M0 = std_msgs::Float32_<std::allocator<void> >, M1 = std_msgs::Float32_<std::allocator<void> >, M2 = std_msgs::Float32_<std::allocator<void> >, M3 = message_filters::NullType, M4 = message_filters::NullType, M5 = message_filters::NullType, M6 = message_filters::NullType, M7 = message_filters::NullType, M8 = message_filters::NullType, typename boost::mpl::at_c<typename message_filters::PolicyBase<M0, M1, M2, M3, M4, M5, M6, M7, M8>::Events, i>::type = ros::MessageEvent<const std_msgs::Float32_<std::allocator<void> > >]’/opt/ros/fuerte/include/message_filters/synchronizer.h:358:5:   instantiated from ‘void message_filters::Synchronizer<Policy>::cb(const typename boost::mpl::at_c<typename Policy::Events, i>::type&) [with int i = 0, Policy = message_filters::sync_policies::ApproximateTime<std_msgs::Float32_<std::allocator<void> >, std_msgs::Float32_<std::allocator<void> >, std_msgs::Float32_<std::allocator<void> > >, typename boost::mpl::at_c<typename Policy::Events, i>::type = ros::MessageEvent<const std_msgs::Float32_<std::allocator<void> > >]’/opt/ros/fuerte/include/message_filters/synchronizer.h:290:5:   [ skipping 3 instantiation contexts ]/opt/ros/fuerte/include/message_filters/synchronizer.h:268:5:   instantiated from ‘void message_filters::Synchronizer<Policy>::connectInput(F0&, F1&, F2&, F3&, F4&, F5&) [with F0 = message_filters::Subscriber<std_msgs::Float32_<std::allocator<void> > >, F1 = message_filters::Subscriber<std_msgs::Float32_<std::allocator<void> > >, F2 = message_filters::Subscriber<std_msgs::Float32_<std::allocator<void> > >, F3 = message_filters::NullFilter<message_filters::NullType>, F4 = message_filters::NullFilter<message_filters::NullType>, F5 = message_filters::NullFilter<message_filters::NullType>, Policy = message_filters::sync_policies::ApproximateTime<std_msgs::Float32_<std::allocator<void> >, std_msgs::Float32_<std::allocator<void> >, std_msgs::Float32_<std::allocator<void> > >]’/opt/ros/fuerte/include/message_filters/synchronizer.h:261:5:   instantiated from ‘void message_filters::Synchronizer<Policy>::connectInput(F0&, F1&, F2&, F3&, F4&) [with F0 = message_filters::Subscriber<std_msgs::Float32_<std::allocator<void> > >, F1 = message_filters::Subscriber<std_msgs::Float32_<std::allocator<void> > >, F2 = message_filters::Subscriber<std_msgs::Float32_<std::allocator<void> > >, F3 = message_filters::NullFilter<message_filters::NullType>, F4 = message_filters::NullFilter<message_filters::NullType>, Policy = message_filters::sync_policies::ApproximateTime<std_msgs::Float32_<std::allocator<void> >, std_msgs::Float32_<std::allocator<void> >, std_msgs::Float32_<std::allocator<void> > >] /opt/ros/fuerte/include/message_filters/synchronizer.h:254:5:   instantiated from ‘void message_filters::Synchronizer<Policy>::connectInput(F0&, F1&, F2&, F3&) [with F0 = message_filters::Subscriber<std_msgs::Float32_<std::allocator<void> > >, F1 = message_filters::Subscriber<std_msgs::Float32_<std::allocator<void> > >, F2 = message_filters::Subscriber<std_msgs::Float32_<std::allocator<void> > >, F3 = message_filters::NullFilter<message_filters::NullType>, Policy = message_filters::sync_policies::ApproximateTime<std_msgs::Float32_<std::allocator<void> >, std_msgs::Float32_<std::allocator<void> >, std_msgs::Float32_<std::allocator<void> > >]’/opt/ros/fuerte/include/message_filters/synchronizer.h:247:5:   instantiated from ‘void message_filters::Synchronizer<Policy>::connectInput(F0&, F1&, F2&) [with F0 = message_filters::Subscriber<std_msgs::Float32_<std::allocator<void> > >, F1 = message_filters::Subscriber<std_msgs::Float32_<std::allocator<void> > >, F2 = message_filters::Subscriber<std_msgs::Float32_<std::allocator<void> > >, Policy = message_filters::sync_policies::ApproximateTime<std_msgs::Float32_<std::allocator<void> >, std_msgs::Float32_<std::allocator<void> >, std_msgs::Float32_<std::allocator<void> > >]’/opt/ros/fuerte/include/message_filters/synchronizer.h:168:5:   instantiated from ‘message_filters::Synchronizer<Policy>::Synchronizer(const Policy&, F0&, F1&, F2&) [with F0 = message_filters::Subscriber<std_msgs::Float32_<std::allocator<void> > >, F1 = message_filters::Subscriber<std_msgs::Float32_<std::allocator<void> > >, F2 = message_filters::Subscriber<std_msgs::Float32_<std::allocator<void> > >, Policy = message_filters::sync_policies::ApproximateTime<std_msgs::Float32_<std::allocator<void> >, std_msgs::Float32_<std::allocator<void> >, std_msgs::Float32_<std::allocator<void> > >]’/home/abc/ros_workspace/prototype/src/prototype_node.cpp:141:68:   instantiated from here/opt/ros/fuerte/include/message_filters/sync_policies/approximate_time.h:612:117: error: ‘value’ is not a member of ‘ros::message_traits::TimeStamp<std_msgs::Float32_<std::allocator<void> >, void>’/opt/ros/fuerte/include/message_filters/sync_policies/approximate_time.h:620:119: error: ‘value’ is not a member of ‘ros::message_traits::TimeStamp<std_msgs::Float32_<std::allocator<void> >, void>’make[2]: *** [CMakeFiles/prototype_node.dir/src/prototype_node.o] Error 1make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/prototype_node.dir/all] Error 2-------------------------------------------------------------------------------}
```

What could go wrong? Thanks.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/186281/problem-using-callback-with-multiple-arguments-via-approximatetime-synchronizer/) by [alfa_80](https://answers.ros.org/users/121/alfa_80/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1053 on 2014-07-12

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The std_msgs/Float32 message type has no header and hence no time stamp. As a result, time synchroniser will not work.
See the documentation: http://docs.ros.org/api/std_msgs/html/msg/Float32.html

The reason why the code from the previous answer works is because sensor_msgs/PointCloud2 does have a header (and time stamp - http://docs.ros.org/api/sensor_msgs/html/msg/PointCloud2.html).

It's a bit of a late answer, but I hope it helps.

---

Originally posted by [Murilo F. M.](https://answers.ros.org/users/2499/murilo-f.-m./) with karma: 806 on 2014-08-13

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [rasoo](https://answers.ros.org/users/26785/rasoo/) on 2016-11-26**:
And what is the solution for this kind of problem with a message type without header  like float or bool ?

**Comment by [Murilo F. M.](https://answers.ros.org/users/2499/murilo-f.-m./) on 2017-06-27**:
You can either use a message type which has a header, or create a custom message with a header and the primitive data type, e.g., `FloatStamped` or `BoolStamped`.

**Comment by [rasoo](https://answers.ros.org/users/26785/rasoo/) on 2017-06-27**:
Although its again a bit late ;)... but I am really glad to get answere from you :) thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Ok...

Here is the code that is working for me...and I hope that it will come for you.

Add these lines in CMakeLists.txt

```
FIND_PACKAGE(PCL 1.5)

include_directories(${PCL_INCLUDE_DIRS})
link_directories(${PCL_LIBRARY_DIRS})
add_definitions(${PCL_DEFINITIONS})

rosbuild_add_executable(test_file src/test_file.cpp)
rosbuild_link_boost(test_file signals)
target_link_libraries(test_file ${PCL_LIBRARIES} ${BOOST_LIBRARIES})
```

I dont think that there is need to add PCL..Just added to test if my file is working here...

Next in create a new package and try this thing..

```
    /*********************************   Header Files   ***************************/   

#include <ros/ros.h>
#include <sensor_msgs/PointCloud2.h>

// PCL specific includes

#include <pcl/ros/conversions.h>
#include <pcl/point_cloud.h>
#include <pcl/point_types.h>

#include <pcl/visualization/cloud_viewer.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <pcl/io/io.h>
#include <pcl/io/pcd_io.h>
#include <pcl/common/transforms.h>

#include <message_filters/subscriber.h>
#include <message_filters/time_synchronizer.h>

#include <message_filters/synchronizer.h>
#include <message_filters/sync_policies/approximate_time.h>

 /************************************   End of Header Files   **************************/

    using namespace sensor_msgs;
    using namespace message_filters;

    ros::Publisher pub_sub1_sub2;

    void cloud_cb ( const sensor_msgs::PointCloud2ConstPtr& sub2_input,  
                   const sensor_msgs::PointCloud2ConstPtr& sub1_input)
 {
     //processing
     std::cout<< " I am here! " <<std::endl;
      pub_sub1_sub2.publish (*sub2_input);

 }


         int main (int argc, char** argv)
    {
              // Initialize ROS
              ros::init (argc, argv, "testing");
              ros::NodeHandle nh;
              ROS_INFO("Starting ");
    
              message_filters::Subscriber<sensor_msgs::PointCloud2> sub2(nh, "topic1", 5);
              message_filters::Subscriber<sensor_msgs::PointCloud2> sub1(nh, "topic2", 5);
 
typedef sync_policies::ApproximateTime<sensor_msgs::PointCloud2, sensor_msgs::PointCloud2> MySyncPolicy;
     
      // ApproximateTime takes a queue size as its constructor argument, hence MySyncPolicy(10)
              Synchronizer<MySyncPolicy> sync(MySyncPolicy(10), sub2, sub1);
              sync.registerCallback(boost::bind(&cloud_cb, _1, _2));
               pub_sub1_sub2 = nh.advertise<sensor_msgs::PointCloud2> ("/cloud", 1);    

              // Spin
              ros::spin ();
               return 0;
    
       }
```

UPDATE

Two suggestions to try.

1. i think you have to declare it in a different way, try something like this in declaring subscribers."  `message_filters::Subscriber<std_msgs::Float32<std::allocator<void> > > sub1`
2. Look at this http://wiki.ros.org/roscpp/Overview/MessagesCustomAllocators

---

Originally posted by [sai](https://answers.ros.org/users/2967/sai/) with karma: 1935 on 2014-07-12

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [alfa_80](https://answers.ros.org/users/121/alfa_80/) on 2014-07-14**:
I've just tried your test code and it works perfectly. I guess it could be something wrong somewhere with the data type used, as in my case I use Float32 and in your case you use PointCloud2. Could you please spot anything that I have overlooked regarding the data type used? Thanks.

**Comment by [sai](https://answers.ros.org/users/2967/sai/) on 2014-07-14**:
I cannot find any but by replacing the variables in the test code, were you able to solve your problem and move ahead ?

I think its because of adding this in CMakeLists.txt `rosbuild_link_boost(test_file signals)`

**Comment by [alfa_80](https://answers.ros.org/users/121/alfa_80/) on 2014-07-14**:
Your test code is actually working perfectly on my system. I am still stuck by the way with my own code. I am guessing it is something to do with Float32 that I am using.

**Comment by [sai](https://answers.ros.org/users/2967/sai/) on 2014-07-14**:
did you try changing the subscribing topic names to different topics ?

**Comment by [alfa_80](https://answers.ros.org/users/121/alfa_80/) on 2014-07-14**:
I think that way is similar to testing your test code in that I have already subscribed to a different data type of PointCloud2.

**Comment by [sai](https://answers.ros.org/users/2967/sai/) on 2014-07-14**:
@alfa_80 look at the updated answer

**Comment by [alfa_80](https://answers.ros.org/users/121/alfa_80/) on 2014-07-14**:
I've tried different way declaring the subscriber, but it the first place it gives an error in eclipse editor while editing. It says "invalid template argument". In your code, there is an extra closing ">", i guess but I tried both with and without extra one, none is functional.